# CSS hover functionality not responding when hovering over a merged topojson section of map.

Tags: d3.js, topojson

Using Mike Bostock's bl.ock on merging states into a single polygon https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5416440 while also trying to incorporate some CSS hovering which highlights the entire merged section.

The states that are not merged hover just fine, but the merged sections don't respond to the CSS hover. Hoping for an explanation as to why it ignores it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>

.states {
  fill: white;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 0.5px;
}

.states :hover {
  fill: grey;
}

.east {
  fill: orange;
}

.east :hover {
  fill: white;
}

.west {
  fill: blue;
}

.west :hover {
  fill: white;
}

.state-borders {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 0.5px;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  pointer-events: none;
}

</style>
<svg width="960" height="600"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v2.min.js"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg");

var path = d3.geoPath();

var east = {
  "26": 1, "29": 1, "37": 1, "31": 1, "33": 1,
  "34": 1, "36": 1, "39": 1, "42": 1, "44": 1, "45": 1, "47": 1, "51": 1,
  "50": 1, "55": 1, "54": 1
};

var west = {
  "9": 1, "10": 1, "12": 1, "13": 1, "19": 1, "17": 1, "18": 1, "21": 1,
  "25": 1, "24": 1, "23": 1
};

d3.json("https://d3js.org/us-10m.v1.json", function(error, us) {
  if (error) throw error;

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "states")
      .selectAll("path")
      .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.states).features)
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("d", path);

  svg.append("path")
      .attr("class", "east")
      .datum(topojson.merge(us, us.objects.states.geometries.filter(function(d) { return d.id in east; })))
      .attr("d", path);

  svg.append("path")
      .attr("class", "west")
      .datum(topojson.merge(us, us.objects.states.geometries.filter(function(d) { return d.id in west; })))
      .attr("d", path);

  svg.append("path")
      .attr("class", "state-borders")
      .attr("d", path(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function(a, b) { return a !== b; })));

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct CSS should be:

```
.east:hover { //<-- note no spaces!
  fill: white;
}
```

I'm not sure how it's working on the states.  You'll notice if you change it to the proper format, it works on all the "other" states at once (it fills the whole `g`).  Some how the broken hover syntax with the inheritance from the parent `g` is doing what you want!

Here's the correct code that I think you really are after:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
  .state {
    fill: white;
    stroke: #000;
    stroke-width: 0.5px;
  }
  
  .state:hover {
    fill: grey;
  }
  
  .east {
    fill: orange;
  }
  
  .east:hover {
    fill: white;
  }
  
  .west {
    fill: blue;
  }
  
  .west:hover {
    fill: white;
  }
  
  .state-borders {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
    stroke-width: 0.5px;
    stroke-linejoin: round;
    stroke-linecap: round;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
</style>
<svg width="960" height="600"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v2.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var svg = d3.select("svg");

  var path = d3.geoPath();

  var east = {
    "26": 1,
    "29": 1,
    "37": 1,
    "31": 1,
    "33": 1,
    "34": 1,
    "36": 1,
    "39": 1,
    "42": 1,
    "44": 1,
    "45": 1,
    "47": 1,
    "51": 1,
    "50": 1,
    "55": 1,
    "54": 1
  };

  var west = {
    "9": 1,
    "10": 1,
    "12": 1,
    "13": 1,
    "19": 1,
    "17": 1,
    "18": 1,
    "21": 1,
    "25": 1,
    "24": 1,
    "23": 1
  };

  d3.json("https://d3js.org/us-10m.v1.json", function(error, us) {
    if (error) throw error;

    svg.append("g")
      .selectAll("path")
      .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.states).features)
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("class", "state")
      .attr("d", path);

    svg.append("path")
      .attr("class", "east")
      .datum(topojson.merge(us, us.objects.states.geometries.filter(function(d) {
        return d.id in east;
      })))
      .attr("d", path);

    svg.append("path")
      .attr("class", "west")
      .datum(topojson.merge(us, us.objects.states.geometries.filter(function(d) {
        return d.id in west;
      })))
      .attr("d", path);

    svg.append("path")
      .attr("class", "state-borders")
      .attr("d", path(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function(a, b) {
        return a !== b;
      })));

  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, Mark! I don't know what was tripping me up but your code worked great. Time to compare the before/after and learn. Thank you again.